# CodeIgniter Form information

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a controller with a add() function and create() function. The add function posts to create.

The form is displayed using the form helper. In the add() function, I have an array to set the form input attributes that looks like the following:

```
$this->data['form'] = array(
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'
        ),
        'media_name' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'    => 'media_name',
            'name'  => 'media_name',
            'value' => set_value('media_name')
        ),
        'media_link' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'    => 'media_link',
            'name'  => 'media_link',
            'value' => set_value('media_link')
        ),
        'media_width' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'    => 'media_width',
            'name'  => 'media_width',
            'size'  => '4',
            'maxlength' => '4',
            'value' => ($this->form_validation->set_value('media_width')) ? $this->form_validation->set_value('media_width') : '640'
        ),
        'media_height' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'    => 'media_height',
            'name'  => 'media_height',
            'value' => ($this->form_validation->set_value('media_height')) ? $this->form_validation->set_value('media_height') : '360'
        ),
        'media_description' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'    => 'media_desription',
            'name'  => 'media_desription',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('media_desription')
        )
    );
```

When I post to the create() function, I lose access to the data['form'] values. Should all this information just be in the view or is it possible to put it in the model so I can load it whenever needed? When I tried to put it in the model, I had issues with the 'value' attributes even if I loaded the form_validation library in the model.

Comment: If validation fails, I ran $this->add() from my controller to go back to the add() function. This works and shows errors, however, the URI is stays /create and I would like it to go back to /add. /create should only be for POST.

Answer (score 0):

Because the controller class is renewed when a new request comes, so the problem with your code is that, $this->data is created when you visit the add function, while when you post to create function, the controller class is renewed again, there is no $this->data at all at this time.

If you want to pass data from one request to another request, you can pass the data via view or model.

Hope helps!

Comment: I understand that it is getting renewed so that it goes away. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by passing it to the view or model.

My problem seems to be mostly if the form does not validate, how can I go back to the add() function and URI? My create() function should never be rendering a view or showing up in the browser address bar.

Comment: maybe you can store the data in session

Comment: You could extend `CI_Controller` to `MY_Controller` and put your code there. This way, you have `$this->data` on any controller that extends `MY_Controller`. Take a look at [this](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).